# Insert a variable image through php

Tags: php, html

I have a customer account page, and I want the customer's specific image to show up when they log in to the specific account. I am trying something like

```
<?php echo '<img src=img/user_id/"' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . '.jpg">';
  ?>
```

I obviously am storing all these images based on their user_id they created in my image folder. I basically have no experience in php, so talk to me like you would a child.

Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what's the question?

Comment: What is the problem now ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure what you ask, but there's a mistake in your html:

It should be thus:

```
<?php echo '<img src="img/user_id/' . $_SESSION['user_id'] . '.jpg">' ?>
```

Or - which makes more sense:

```
<img src="img/user_id/<?= $_SESSION['user_id'] ?>.jpg">
```